# Unable to plot 3d graph in python when dimensions of x and y axes are not the same

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot a 3d graph using matplotlib on Python. Here is a copy of the code:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

#global variable a 
a = 1
#time steps = 100
T = 100 
#length steps = 50
L = 50


time = [i for i in range(T)]
#checking for 50 points onthe vent only
length = [i for i in range(L)]
#creating the concentration matrix for each point in the vent at each point in time. The innerlists represent the point on the vent. Each such list is the time stamp.
concentration = [ [i for i in range(L)] for j in range(T)]


#Boundary condition at x=0
def h(t):
  return (1/(t+(1/a))) + a



#Boundary condition at x=L
def j(t):
  return (-1/(t+(1/a))) + a


#Initilal condition is that the temperate is 0 everywhere on the vent. Hence we are setting the concentration to equal 0 at every point in the vent when time is equal to 0
for i in range(5):
  concentration[0][i] = 2

for i in range(5,L):
  concentration[0][i] = 0

#Setting the boundary conditions
for i in range(T):
  concentration[i][0] = h(i)
  concentration[i][L-1] = j(i)



#Doing the numerical solution based on the formula in Walter Strauss
for j in range(0,L-1): #j is the position column
  for n in range(0,T-1): #n is the time row
    concentration[n+1][j] = concentration[n][j+1] + concentration[n][j-1] + (-1)*concentration[n][j]
```

This part of the code runs fine, and without any errors. However, when I try to plot the data using the following instructions:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(time, length, concentration, cmap='binary')
ax.set_xlabel('rod')
ax.set_ylabel('time')
ax.set_zlabel('concentration');
```

I get an error. The error reads:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-321ea987eeb6> in <module>()
     53 fig = plt.figure()
     54 ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
---> 55 ax.scatter(time, length, concentration, cmap='binary')
     56 ax.set_xlabel('rod')
     57 ax.set_ylabel('time')

2 frames
<__array_function__ internals> in broadcast_arrays(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py in _broadcast_shape(*args)
    189     # use the old-iterator because np.nditer does not handle size 0 arrays
    190     # consistently
--> 191     b = np.broadcast(*args[:32])
    192     # unfortunately, it cannot handle 32 or more arguments directly
    193     for pos in range(32, len(args), 31):

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Could someone help me understand where the error is coming from? I don't think this is a computational error in the first half of the code since it runs just fine. The dimensions of the concentration matrix, and the length and time matrix all match up perfectly well. But the 3d plotting gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a scatter plot (you might consider a surface plot, such as ax.plot_wireframe(), if you want to create a continuous surface) of every single point in your `concentration` list, you will plot 100x50 points. Your x and y values have to follow this shape (hence the error message you observed), so they cannot stay 100 and 50, but need to be 2-dimensional, too. Hence, you have to create a meshgrid that transforms both dimensions into arrays with the dimensions 100x50.

After adding...

```
import numpy as np
time, length = np.meshgrid(time, length)
```

... a plot is created and shown.